# Stubbing and mocking in Ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, stub

I think I understand that is going on here, but I'd like to make sure.

There is some code that needs unit testing with the File methods stubbed out:

```
temp = File.new(uri.path)
@path = Rails.root.to_s + "/tmp/" +uri.path.split("/").last
File.open(@path, "w"){|f| f.write(temp.read)} if File.exists(temp)
temp.close
```

The unit test has:

```
file = mock(File)
File.stub(:new).and_return(file)
File.stub(:open).and_return(file)
file.stub(:close)
```

I'm guessing the difference between `File.stub` and `file.stub` is that `File.stub` will stub the method on the File class, whereas `file.stub` (`file` is a mock `File` object) will stub any method on a `File` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `stub(:method)` will stub the method on the object you called it on. So your call to `File.stub(:new)` will stub all calls to File.new (class method). The call to `file.stub(:close)` will stub **all calls** to file.close but **only on the instance you called stub on**

If you want to stub all calls to any instance of File you can:

1. use [any_instance](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class)
2. or you can stub File.new to make it only return file objects with a stubbed close, like you do in:

   ```
   File.stub(:new).and_return(file)
   File.stub(:open).and_return(file)
   ```

Please be aware that in case 2 every call to File.new after that will return the **same instance**. In case that's not what you want you can always hand a block to stub, where you can provide a [substitute](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/method-stubs/stub-with-substitute-implementation) for the stubbed metod

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is right.

```
File.stub(:new)
```

stubs the call `new` on the class `File`

```
file.stub(:close)
```

stubs the call `close` on `file` object

In your case, you can also do

```
file = mock(File, :close => nil) #this will create a mocked object that responds with nil when close is called
```